# Provider, Factory, AbstractFactory в C#. Что есть что?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, dependency-injection

1. Насколько я понимаю, класс, благодаря которому мы получаем экземпляры классов определенного типа может быть назван `SomeClassProvider` или `SomeClassFactory`.
   В чем принципиальная разница? Как правильно называть?
2. Что такое **Abstract Factory**, и как этот паттерн связан с Dependency injection? Например, в ***Castle.Windsor*** есть фабрика **TypedFactory** - какой из вышеперечисленных паттернов она реализует?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Factory именно создает объекты. Provider просто "предоставляет экземпляры". Т.е. он может не создавать каждый раз новый экземпляр, а возвращать один и тот же. Но принципиальной разницы нет. Называйте как угодно, главное чтобы название отражало суть.
2. Dependency Injection собирает граф зависимых объектов из готовых экземляров (причем так, что сами экземпляры не знают о конкретных типах других экземпляров, только об их интерфейсах). AF умеет создавать экземпляр класса и известным интерфейсом, но заранее неизвестным конкретным типом. В случае Castle.Windsor - DI умеет дергать AF для создания объектов, которые DI потом свяжет вместе с собой.

Практически все, на чем написано Factory - это реализация паттерна Abstract Factory. Кроме случая, когда ваша предметная область - управление настоящими заводами-фабриками.

UPD: сорри, не удержался:

[RequestProcessorFactoryFactory](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/server/RequestProcessorFactoryFactory)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [*смайл "когнитивный диссонанс"*]

Comment: По поводу AbstractFactory, не совсем верно говорить, что почти все фабрики, это реализация этого паттерна. Чтобы понять, почему эта фабрика называется "абстрактной", надо взглянуть на схему реализации этого паттерна, например [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) На схеме видно, что есть две параллеьных иеерархии наследования - фабрик и создаваемых объектов.

Comment: Если у вас нет этих иеерархий наследования, а есть одна фабрика, создающая объекты, то есть смысл называть ее просто "фабрикой". Кроме того иногда пишут статические классы с методами, создающими объекты, и называют их "статическими фабриками".

Comment: @ValeO для прояснения вопросов, связанных с паттернами проектирования самый верный путь - прочитать [классическую книгу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) Банды четырех. Рано или поздно вы все равно к ней прийдете, и если вы сейчас размышляете на тему паттернов, значит время уже пришло.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev понятие фабрики и сам паттерн Abstract Factory достаточно размылся с тех пор, когда GoF написали свою книгу. И даже в GoF приведен лишь пример реализации. Никаких требований на существование двух параллельных иерархий классов нет. У GoF просто приведен минимальный пример. А минимальный пример требует двух конкретных фабрик и двух разных типов объектов.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev фабрика - это любое решение проблемы виртуального конструктора. Т.е. или Factory Method, или AF. Если класс называется SomethingFactory - это скорее всего реализация AF.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev если вы хотите написать свой собственный ответ, про то, что фабрика называется абстрактной не потому, что суть паттерна в определении интерфейса фабрики (==абстрактного класса в C++), и создании нескольких его реализаций, а вот именно в параллельных иерархиях наследования - пишите. Не надо спамить в комментах к чужим ответам.

Comment: Всем спасибо, буду изучать. @PashaPash, истина в споре) Комментарии полезные.

Comment: @ValeO да не заморачивайтесь. Factory - это что-то, что создает объект. Просто обычно это именно пара интерфейс фабрики + конкретная фабрика. Которая решает немного не те проблемы, которые GoF решали изначально. Эдакая "половина фабрики". Но суть та же - это решение проблемы отсутствия виртуальных конструторов в мейнстримных яп.

Comment: @PashaPash я понимаю слово "абстрактный" в паттерне абстрактная фабрика таким образом - мы описываем абстракцию фабрики (`IAbstractFactory`), затем мы создаем реализации этого интерфейса (`ConcreteFactory1`, `ConcreteFactory2` etc.) и используем нужную нам реализацию в зависимости от ситуации. Если есть одна единственная фабрика `ConcreteFactory1` не реализующая никакие интерфейсы, то это просто фабрика. То есть класс создающий объекты это `фабрика`, если есть абстракция для создания объектов, позволяющая создать несколько реализаций, это уже `абстрактная фабрика`.

Comment: @PashaPash в целом согласен, что здесь не стоит заморачиваться. Я не пишу все это в отдельном ответе, потому что считаю ваш ответ - верным и достаточным.

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev "абстрактная фабрика" это две разных вещи. Это название всего паттерна. И название конкретного класса в стандартной реализации этого паттерна - предка в иерархии фабрик. В C++ не было интерфейсов, были абстрактные классы. Было принято приписывать Abstract. Сейчас в реализации AF будет просто какой-нибудь `IFactory`. Согласен, `ConcreteFactory1` без интерфейса - это не AF. Но это скорее всего неправильно названный класс-хелпер. Предлагаю замять для ясности.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен